# How can I solve err_unknown_url_scheme for Amplify Google authentication?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, android-studio, google-chrome, aws-amplify

How can I solve err_unknown_url_scheme for Amplify Google authentication? I have implemented amplify federated (hosted UI) authentication in iOS and Android.Only in Android after Google 2 factor authentication I get this error.

Tried changing AndroidManifest.xml , my code but still after logging in i get the error but the user is logged in succesfully and everything works except this error page that i need to get rid of.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: <activity           android:name="com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoauth.activities.CustomTabsRedirectActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="myapp://"
                    tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError" />
            </intent-filter>
   </activity>